# proof check: $f$ maps positive integers to positive integers. $f(m)f(n)=f(mn)$ and $m+n$ divides $f(m)+f(n)$

Tags: number-theory, functions, proof-writing, solution-verification, contest-math

Find all possible functions $f$ such that $f$ maps positive integers to positive integers, $f(m)f(n)=f(mn)$ and $m+n$ divides $f(m)+f(n)$.

Can we safely say that $f(m)=m^k \cdot a$ (where $a$ is a constant number)? pOne of my students is arguing with me and he says we can.

Comment: What is your student's argument?

Comment: Without a proof, no.

Comment: Well, technically the question does not say "with proof".  If proofs were expected, then doing it without proof is no good.  But did you actually say in advance that proofs were expected?

Comment: Also note: $f(m) = am^k$ satisfies $f(m)f(n) = f(mn)$ only if $a=1$.

Comment: You don't need to do any proofs to show that $m^k\cdot a$ doesn't always work e.g., for $k = 1$ and $a = 2$.

Comment: And note $m+n$ divides $f(m)+f(n)$ also fails for $f(m)=m^k$ with $k \ge 2$.

Comment: @GEdgar $$\frac{m^3+n^3}{m+n}=m^2-mn+n^2$$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout ... Good point. I guess I mean if fails for $k$ even...

Comment: @GEdgar yes, i did

Comment: Well, presumably you know the answer.  *Is* the student correct?  I'd say you can't make non-obvious claims without argument. I see nothing that makes that claim "obvious".

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer,

$f(1)=f(1)^2$, so $f(1)=1$, since $f:\Bbb Z^+\rightarrow\Bbb Z^+$.

Since $m+n\mid f(m)+f(n)$ let $m=n$, then $m\mid f(m)$. We can factor $m=\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}p_i^{a_i}$ so that $$f(m)=\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}f(p_i)^{a_i}$$ is determined by where $f$ maps the prime numbers. We have $f(p_i)=p_ic_i$, where $c_i$ is some constant. Since $p_i+1\mid f(p_i)+1$ we must have $$\frac{p_ic_i+1}{p_i+1}\in\Bbb Z$$ which happens if and only if $c_i=1+k_i(p_i+1)$ for some constant $k_i$.

---

$f(m)=m^ka$ works if $a=1$, since $f(1)=1$, but fails for every even $k$ in general, since $$2m+m\not\mid 2^km^k+m^k$$ if $3\not\mid m$.